# SSRS Missing Folder in Tile View

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

one user is having a problem with a missing folder in SSRS which they can see in Details view but not in Tile view.  All other users are able to see and use this folder in tile view. This folder doesn't appear to be hidden as the checkbox "Hide in tile view" in its properties isn't checked off and the folder isn't white/gray when looking at it in details view on their own computer.  For the time being they can access the folder in details view but they would much prefer to open it in tile view.

Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: If you click on the dropdown  to manage the folder there is a checkbox "Hide in Tile View". Have a look to see if this is checked.

Comment: As I believed I mention above "Hide in tile view" is not checked off  thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your user can see it in detail view proves that the necessary permissions are in place. As there is only one (or a handful) of users experiencing this problem, I would suggest the problem might be in the browser. I would suggest trying the following in Internet Explorer (which I assume you're using as SSRS works best with IE):

Tools => Internet Options => Under Browsing History click the Delete Button and delete all Temporary Internet files, Cookies, and History.

Close all instances of the browser and reopen. If this fixed the problem, then you want to do the following:

Tools => Internet Options => Under the Advanced tab, check the "Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed"

Admittedly, this is a shot in the dark. However, I've run into problems with SSRS before where browser caching has produced undesirable results.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no changes